# Why did the Pandavas have so many wives?

Tags: women, marriage, pandavas, sex

Why did the Pandavas have so many wives?

I know they had multiple wives each, but why did they have so many wives? Was it just for pleasure? Or did they want lots of male lineages for political purposes?

Comment: Arjuna had four wives; Yuddhishtira, 2; Bhima, 3; Sahadeva and Nakula, 2 each. Draupadi was, of course, the common wife among the five. This does not seem like "so many."

Comment: @AravindSuresh Why did they have multiple wives?

Comment: for comparison, Dasharatha from the Ramayana had three wives. I believe it has more to do with the customs of the time than with anything strategic. I am still digging for a scriptural reference.

Comment: @AravindSuresh Dasharatha had 3 primary wives, but he had hundreds of wives because he kept marrying a woman every time Parashurama came, and that's because Parashurama would kill any kshatriya he sees, except one who was recently married.

Answer (score 1):

Obviouly In old times King has many wives because of political relationship.

Same happens with Pandavas also.

After getting marries with Draupadi , they also had to marry another kingdom princess for political relationship.

Such as Krishna planned to marry her sister "Subhadra" with Arjun so that pandas become strong.

Comment: Welcome Adirya To Hinduism SE! When answering the questions on this site it is necessary to add some references in the answer as a support.You can also visit help section of the site to know more about how to write a good answer. –